# Geometry problem without trigonometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> [image]
> In the figure, $AB \bot CK$, $\angle B = 2\angle A$, $I$ and $J$ are the mid-points of $AB$ and $BC$. Prove that $IK = \frac{1}{2} BC$.

It can easily be solved with trigonometry by letting $\angle CAB = \theta, BC = \sin \theta$ and show that both $IK$ and $\frac{1}{2}BC$ are $\frac{\sin \theta}{2}$, however, I am interested in a pure geometry solution if there exists any, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you see a right angle, there must be a circle somewhere.

Comment: Why is the point $J$ part of the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be. I just realized that it is useless. Or is the problem setter trying to give a hint? I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reflect point $B$ with respect to segment $CK$ to obtain point $B’$ as shown in figure below

[image: Triangle]

Since $\angle KB’C =2\angle KAC$, triangle $CB’A$ is isosceles with $AB’=B’C$.

$BC=B’C=AB’=AB-2BK$

$IK=IB-BK=\frac{1}{2}AB-BK$

Answer (score 5):

The right angle at $K$ implies (by [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem)) that $K$ lies on a semicircle with center $J$ and diameter $\overline{BC}$; hence, $|JK|=|JB|=|JC|=\frac12|BC|$. Also, midsegment $\overline{IJ}$ of $\triangle ABC$ is parallel to $\overline{AC}$.

[image]

A little angle chasing yields $\angle KIJ=\angle IJK$, so that $|IK|=|JK|$. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Join point J and K. Since j is the midpoint of hypotenuse

=> Segment JK = BJ = CJ = BC/2  (given)

=> Angle (BCK) = Angle (90° - 2A)

=> Angle (JKC) = Angle (90° - 2A) ( since ∆JKC is issoceles)

=> Angle (IJK) = 180° - (90° + 90 - 2A) - A ( angle sum property of ∆)

=> Angle (IJK) = Angle(A)

=> IK = JK (∆ IJK is issoceles)

=> IK = JK = BC/2   Proved